# Kernel panic reports. Fans max speed. Frozen mac.

Tags: macos, fan, kernel, macbook-pro-retina

My computer keeps shutting down unexpectedly, and also freezes sometime, followed by either unresponsive sleep mode, or shut down. Also fans run at max speed usually before it clashes. I keep getting kernel panic reports with some of the classes too (not all of them). I really need some help! - Thanks in advance!

Already run apple diagnostics: said it was ok. Already tried resetting PRAM and SMC. Didn't work well. Also tried deleting all cache files. Didn't work either.

```
Anonymous UUID:       4D78B3E3-587B-140D-0818-60B896033912

Fri Mar  4 22:10:48 2016

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff80099f076b): "soclose: NOFDREF"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-3248.30.4/bsd/kern/uipc_socket.c:1263
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81f3343d20 : 0xffffff80094df792 
0xffffff81f3343da0 : 0xffffff80099f076b 
0xffffff81f3343df0 : 0xffffff8009a17664 
0xffffff81f3343e10 : 0xffffff7f8cefe36c 
0xffffff81f3343f00 : 0xffffff8009513afa 
0xffffff81f3343fb0 : 0xffffff80095ccf77 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall(163.0)[113F310F-1904-3F41-A206-1D275BF7A397]@0xffffff7f8cef9000->0xffffff7f8cf00fff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
15D21

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 15.3.0: Thu Dec 10 18:40:58 PST 2015; root:xnu-3248.30.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: DECC9F02-27D7-31F0-9599-A9EF2873902C
Kernel slide:     0x0000000009200000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8009400000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8009300000
System model name: MacBookPro11,5 (Mac-06F11F11946D27C5)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 23001233915028
last loaded kext at 3810934575: com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.20.22 (addr 0xffffff7f8bd03000, size 110592)
last unloaded kext at 1032708728120: com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver 3.0.1 (addr 0xffffff7f8bd61000, size 8192)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.20.22
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.6.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.7.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   1.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   272.51.3
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.AMDRadeonX4000    1.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.4.3f4
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics   10.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface   5.41.0
com.apple.kext.AMD7000Controller    1.4.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.4.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.12.6
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.13
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferAzul  10.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 86
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTopCaseDriver  86
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.8.5
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1020.17.1a1
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.8
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 38
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   163
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 272.51.3
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   108.0.1
com.apple.driver.CoreCaptureResponder   1
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   1.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.4.3f4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.4.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 272.51.3
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 272.51.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   204.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.12.6
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d7
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.12.6
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    205.1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.7
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   181
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  304.10
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDTransport  5
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1110.26
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.8.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 5.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 417.2
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro11,5, BootROM MBP114.0172.B07, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.5 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.30f2
Graphics: AMD Radeon R9 M370X, AMD Radeon R9 M370X, PCIe, 2048 MB
Graphics: Intel Iris Pro, Intel Iris Pro, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364B544631473634485A2D314736453120
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364B544631473634485A2D314736453120
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x152), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.94.136.1a1)
Bluetooth: Version 4.4.3f4 16616, 3 services, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0512G, 500.28 GB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: Card Reader
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 27.1
```

Comment: See if its a HDD issue. Next I would try and clean the mac out and see if it needs any new paste if its not under warranty or if you dont mind taking it apart.

Answer (score 0):

It could still be a harddrive issue. My boyfriend's ProBook (Late 2011 model) had the exact same thing happen just this week. You can try to boot your Mac from an external drive to see if it will bypass the harddrive to try and rule out the HD.

If your Mac is older than 2013 (You didn't specify), you can shut the computer down, press the D key, and while holding it turn the computer on. It'll take it a bit to start up. After the language prompt, you can choose which test you want to perform. It will tell you if your HD is OK or not.

Another thing you can do is try Mac Recovery from the site.

Now, if it's not the HD, and Mac Recovery doesn't work then it's more than likely the Logic Board.